# KOMA option parskip=full not working in tabu X column

Tags: tabu, parskip

I'd like to have a full empty line between paragraphs and no indentation. Setting the `parskip = full`option accomplishes this but doesn't work inside `tabu`tables as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{X[0.5]X[0.5]}
\blindtext 

\blindtext
& 
\blindtext 

\blindtext \\
\end{tabu}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

What is the best way of accomplishing the intended formatting inside the `tabu`environment?

Comment: The parskip is set to zero in parboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Within `parbox`es, the parskip is set to 0pt. You can save the parskip that was active before the environment and use it in the tabular, best to make new columntypes.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\saveparskip}
\setlength{\saveparskip}{\parskip}
\begin{tabu}{>{\setlength{\parskip}{\saveparskip}}X[0.5]X[0.5]}
    \blindtext 

    \blindtext & \blindtext 

    \blindtext \\
\end{tabu}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Generally, having paragraphs in a tabular environment is a sure sign for misusing. Have you considered a list-environment instead?

Comment: It would have to be a list environment with no symbol / numbering.